# Best RxJava2 approarch for this list of functions?

Tags: android, rx-java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I'm not looking for anyone to write code for me, I'm only hoping to get some advice on how best to use RxJava2 to achieve my requirements.

What strategy, which operators... I'm only a novice with Rx, so I would welcome all opinions. Thank you.

**My simple list of functions**

> 1. Check if output folder exists, if not create it.
> 2. Check assets for folders and files.
>
>    - First find folder 'W' and check for any folders, if found then check for a file type.
>    - If the file type is found then save temp > zip temp > save zip > delete temps.
>    - Lastly find folders 'X, Y, and Z' and use their contents to create simple models.

Comment: Why would use use RxJava for any of that?  Its all procedural code.  Even if you want it off the UI thread, use a Thread.

Comment: That's a solid point. However this will be looping thru a decent amount of files, opening streams for the assets, writing files, zipping. I've actually done some of it w/o rx, but the code is heavy, and having it chain into my ui becomes a little less neat than it could be. But I understand what you're saying.